# Alert view is working in one class, but not the other

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, class

I have a class name viewController and it has the following code below and it works fine. However, when I call check from my subclass controller it doesn't work the way I want it to.The `UIAlertView` shows up, but it isn't able to detect when button index 0 is touched.Any workaround for this.

```
    -(void)check{
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose!"
                                                message:@"Play Again?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
    [alert show];

    }

    - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
          if (buttonIndex == 0) {     // and they clicked OK.
                      ViewController*myNewVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
                      [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:NO];
          }
      }
```

Comment: you have to use custom delegate for this work

Comment: if i am not wrong, you want to call the alert delegate from your subclass?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `UIAlertViewDelegate` in your subclass `.h` file like bellow..

```
@interface yourSubClassViewController :UIViewController <UIAlertViewDelegate>{
   /// your code

}
@end
```

Comment: @MooDoo add `UIAlertViewDelegate`  like my above answer and then let me know.. :)

Comment: how to you display the subclass from main class?? means Push or present this subclass??

Comment: @interface CellButton : UIButton <UIAlertViewDelegate>{
 
        }

Comment: oh no dude this is UIButton class.. i told that on which class you use that UIAlertView like `@interface ViewController : UIViewController< UIAlertViewDelegate>` in UIViewController class define that delegate

Comment: wait, the view controller is my main class and the uibutton class is my subclass. I tried putting the delegate method in both classes.

Comment: add that delegate in `viewcontroller` in which you used that custom `UIButton`

Answer (score 0):

The **Cancel button** will be the index "0", Try for `index==1`.

Use this method:

```
-(void)check{
         UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose!"
                                                message:@"Play Again?"
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:@"PopUp", nil];
    [alert show];

    }

    - (void) alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {
           if (buttonIndex == 0) {     
                     NSLog("Cancel Button clicked);
          }
        else if (buttonIndex == 1)  {
             ViewController*myNewVC = [[ViewController alloc] init];
            [self presentModalViewController:myNewVC animated:NO];
        }
```

Comment: Tried this, doesn't work. If I called on check method in View controller it works. Not sure if this info helps.

Comment: Wt do you mean by **Check mode**.?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use cancel button. Use two buttons **otherButtonTitles** and use the buttons index == 1 and button index == 2 . That may help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `delegate` to your subclass.

```
 -(void)check:(id)delegate{
     UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"You Lose!"
                                            message:@"Play Again?"
                                           delegate:delegate
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];
[alert show];

}
```

and you call it `[self check:self];`